# recursive or simple php loop

Tags: php, recursion, web-scraping

I'm having some problem understanding how to resolve this loop:

I'm developing a small **scraper** for myself and I'm trying to figure out how to loop within 2 methods until all the links are retrieved from the website.

I'm already retrieving the links from the first page but the problem is that I can't make a loop to verify the new links already extracted:

Here is my code:

```
    $scrape->fetchlinks($url);//I scrape the links from the first page from a website

    //for each one found I insert the url in the DB with status = "n"
    foreach ($scrape->results as $result) {
        if ($result) {
            echo "$result \n";
            $crawler->insertUrl($result);
            
            //I select all the links with status = "n" to perform a scrape the stored links
            $urlStatusNList = $crawler->selectUrlByStatus("n");
            
            while (sizeof($urlStatusNList > 1)){
                foreach($urlStatusNList as $sl){
                $scrape->fetchlinks($sl->url);  // I suppose it would retrieve all the new sublinks
                $crawler->insertUrl($sl->url); // insert the sublinks in the db
                $crawler->updateUrlByIdStatus($sl->id, "s"); //update the link scraped with status = "s", so I will not check these links again

                //here I would like to return the loop for each new link in the db with status='n' until the system can not retrieve more links and stops with the script execution
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Any type of help is very welcome. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code you're looking for something like this

```
do
{
    grab new links and add them to database

} while( select all not yet extracted from database > 0 )
```

Will keep going on and on without recursion...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer: Do you mean this?   
 do {
    $scrap->fetchlinks($url);
    
    foreach ($scrap->results as $result) {
        if ($result) {
            echo "$result \n";
            $crawler->insertUrl($result);
        }
    }

} while( $crawler->selectUrlByStatus("n") > 1);

THANKS !

Comment: @rpa yes, should be something among those lines... (didn't really check if the code validates).